# Saving and Deleting in AS3 with XML

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to save something in XML via an AS3 application. I think I have the right save function so I think it lies in my function that pushes data to XML. I also am not sure on the syntax for deleting a node in XML.

Here is my save function:

```
public function saveData():void {
            var file:File =        File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("newPlayer.xml");

            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

            var newXML:XML = new XML("<player></player>");
            newXML.appendChild(playerList.source);
            var str:String = newXML.toString();

            stream.writeUTFBytes(str);
            stream.close();

        }
```

My function that pushes the data to XMl via a text input box:

```
//add a new player from text input into newPlayer.xml
            var newPlayer:XML = <player></player>;

            newPlayer.@name = myTextBox.text;

            playerData.appendChild(newPlayer.@name);

            myPlayerLabel.text = newPlayer.@name;
```

This is in my init function that loads on app complete as well. I think this is what loads the XML back in when I restart the program:

```
public function init():void {
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("newPlayer.xml");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

            var str:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
            stream.close();

            playerData = XML(str);


        }
```

I think the problem lies within the input, but I am not completely sure since XML is new to me. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I am trying to input data to an external XML file then save it, then have it loaded back in when I open up the program again. I don't think it is being pushed to the XML file, its just being set to the label in AS3 not incorporating XML at all. At leas that is my thought. I am somewhat of a noob.

Comment: Make a score keeper app that allows up to 4 players. Pressing the 'plus' button by a player's score should add one to their score, and the 'minus' button should subtract one. Scores should not go below zero. Players can be deleted using the delete button next to their name. New ones can be made by typing in the player name and clicking "add player" at the bottom of the screen. Scores should be able to be saved to the file system, and restored when the application loads again. The method of how to save and load scores (and what format they are stored in) is up to you.

Comment: The above comment is the assignment I was given.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the function you're using to append the new data to the XML. The following line is appending the value of the player attribute to the existing `playerData` rather than the new node you've created:

```
// Appending the attribute as a child     
playerData.appendChild(newPlayer.@name);

// Actually, you want to append the new node
playerData.appendChild(newPlayer);
```